# Export ZPL file on ZebraDesigner 2.2.3

Tags: zebra-printers

I want to export the ZPL file (the one which starts with ^XA) of a given label on Zebradesigner but I can't manage to find any option to do so.
I already looked for a similar question on stackoverflow and I saw a post that seemed to resolve the problem:
[get ZPL Code From zebra designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586865/get-zpl-code-from-zebra-designer)

But I think I don't have the same version cause I don't have a "ports" tab on my printer properties.
So does anyone know how to achieve this with my Zebra version? I have Zebradesigner 2.2.3

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There should be a "Print To File" checkbox or option in the print dialog. This should allow you to save to a .prm file which will contain the raw ZPL including ^XA.

Comment: When I make this procedure I have EPL data not ZPL. I'm use Zebra Design 2.5 (Build 9325). What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0):

There is a print to file checkbox when you print AND you must have a zebra printer driver that would have expected ZPL in order to get this to work right. Then the prn file that is saved will have ZPL that can be sent to a printer. There may be some additional configuration before the first ^XA in the file.