# Edit .prn file for printing it in C#

Tags: c#, .net, zpl

I downloaded ZebraDesigner 3 to create a custom label with a text field where I wrote "Hello World".

Then I wanted to get its source code by "print to file", but when I open it with any editor I can't find what I wrote previously (Hello World).

What I wanted to do is creating a label with some text fields that **are** variable because they will get values from my C# application.

This is what I get from .prn file (file created by printing to file function)

```
^XA
^MMT
^PW639
^LL0320
^LS0
^FO192,128^GFA,01792,01792,00028,:Z64:
eJzt0jFOAzEQBdCxXLjzXsBarjEFYq/kdBRRAhfIebYcxAE4ArMXQKZzgdaMhygOiSKElAKkHRe70iu88/8CLPMfhuUARnmLJhmSJ4L/laFJ9uGS2fHqFuzo4NQ6wtgRBBccbMwLul2zIWEckpopj69489ZsmzFus5otTzMO895K4XyLMa/By7jnKeH9phkHjBy+DCbG2B9sIo8r7tU6eCdM/eE+NfJqHlaE3HaYyqwmnxKuZgQ/mkQ9nhmD7lDtdAdmr7tXk92p7S62z8xmkyUzwvXdUdYfmrX8SkmyppZ17ShrR9WkI/rWUcfabTXpllq3yyzzV+cTr8C3dA==:ED50
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

How can I change those text field from C#?

Comment: You may be better off looking up the ZPL documentation. From the looks of your sample, it may be printing as a graphic.

From the old ZPL documentation I found: "The ^GF (Graphic Field) command allows you to download graphic
field data directly into the bitmap. This command follows the conventions for any other field meaning a field orientation is included with
this command. The graphic field data can be placed at any location
within the bitmap space."

Comment: That is most certainly a ZIP-compressed picture of the label. This is what the driver produces - you can't blame it, it would be pretty hard to convert random document from a random Windows application to a meaningful series of fields with data. If you want those, you need to create the label template yourself from scratch in ZPL and not rely on Windows printing.

Comment: @GSerg fair enough! Thank you for the help though, at least now I'll focus on creating it myself.

Comment: What printer driver are you using? Have you tried ``Generic / Text only`` driver?

Comment: @DelphiCoder, I installed my printer's drivers which are GC420t (EPL) and ZPL one

Comment: Which font did you choose or was chosen by default? Have you tried a native printer font, e.g. ``TRIUMVIRATE COND.``?

Comment: @DelphiCoder Yes I chose "Zebra1"

Comment: Are there any options for the text field, like to print it as text or as graphic? Have you tried other (native) fonts?

Comment: @DelphiCoder Unfortunately there aren't any other options

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing fields in ZPL code after EXPORT from ZebraDesigner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509641/missing-fields-in-zpl-code-after-export-from-zebradesigner)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ["Print to file" feature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13586865/11683) sends the label *image* to the Zebra driver, which converts it to a picture, encodes and ZIP-compresses it, and produces a ZPL file where the only payload is that single picture (and several supplementary commands to set label dimensions and print quantity). You can't blame the driver, it would be pretty hard to convert random document from a random Windows application to a meaningful series of fields with data.

The payload command in your file is

```
^GFA,01792,01792,00028,:Z64:
eJzt0jFOAzEQBdCxXLjzXsBarjEFYq/kdBRRAhfIebYcxAE4ArMXQKZzgdaMhygOiSKElAKkHRe70iu88/8CLPMfhuUARnmLJhmSJ4L/laFJ9uGS2fHqFuzo4NQ6wtgRBBccbMwLul2zIWEckpopj69489ZsmzFus5otTzMO895K4XyLMa/By7jnKeH9phkHjBy+DCbG2B9sIo8r7tU6eCdM/eE+NfJqHlaE3HaYyqwmnxKuZgQ/mkQ9nhmD7lDtdAdmr7tXk92p7S62z8xmkyUzwvXdUdYfmrX8SkmyppZ17ShrR9WkI/rWUcfabTXpllq3yyzzV+cTr8C3dA==:ED50
```

, which unzips to

> [image]

There is not much to edit there.

In order to manually achieve the same, you would write:

```
^XA
^MUm
^FO10,10^A0,10^FDHello World^FS
^MUd
^XZ
```

Comment: Yes, I know there isn't much to edit in that label, but it was just an example because I have a "more complex" label, where I have some text field as Fixed Data, and others should be variable (assigning the value from C# app).
Is there any way to unzip the image to obtain ZPL code?

Comment: @AlessioRaddi The ZPL code, no. The image contains the final rendered bitmap.

Comment: Sorry for being so stubborn, but there is no way to get ZPL code unzipped from "Print to File", right?

Comment: @AlessioRaddi The result you got from "print to file" **is** ZPL. Only the text "Hello World" was converted to bitmap instead of a ZPL text command, whyever

Answer (score 1):

First of all when you crete the label file layout and you introduce the text you will need to use only Zebra printer fonts. At the font style tab you select `"Show printer fonts only"`. With this option all text will remain text and will not be converted to graphic image.

Second part is the driver you use. You need to use `ZPL printer driver` and not `EPL.` You export by selecting print to file or you create a fake port what you direct to a txt file. The print to file option will create PRN file but content is 100% ZPL.

I did this several times and it is working. I created a lot of labels with complex layouts and variables and never had any issue exporting them.