# Missing fields in ZPL code after EXPORT from ZebraDesigner

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I created a layout using ZebraDesigner, it has fields and barcodes. I can only export to a .PRN file that contains "ZPL" code, but when I open the file, the fields are missing, I can only find the barcode's fields.

This is an example of what I am getting

[image]

As you see, there is a lot of strange code.

This is what I expected to see

[image]

The printer still prints all the fields, but the problem is that i need to see those fields in clear into the PRN file because in my program i parse the file template and replace all the fields, for example @idArticolo@ with their corrispondent information picked from a database.

The strange thing is that in the .PRN file i see in clear only the barcode fields.
But normal text is not included.

Comment: In the second screenshot, the text between "@" is my field that i want to replace with database information.

Comment: Seems like it's saving a rendering of the text in the ZPL rather than the actual text. Try reading the ZPL II User Guide, it's pretty easy to just code your own labels with out the designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the font, that was not compatible with the zebra editor.
I used one of the default zebra fonts of ZebraDesginer.